# How to add bump

Tags: cycles-render-engine, rendering

I have model and I want to add the them a bump in cycles and I have this picture
[image]

any one know how to add this kind of bump in cycles?

Comment: This is normal map. To add it to model you add this as image texture node and output 'color' of image texture plug into 'color' input of Normal Map node and then plug Normal map 'Normal' output into shader 'Normal' input. However your model has to be properly UV unwraped If you are trying to put normal map from different model onto yours, in that case you are going to have hard time.

Answer (score 3):

That's not a Bump map but a Normal map. The goal is similar (adding depth), but they work different.

A Bump map is a grayscale picture, where the black pixels mean "hollow" and the white pixels mean "bump".

A Normal map is a color picture, where each color channel (Red, Green, Blue) mean that the normal of the face is oriented along an axis (X, Y, Z).

In Cycles, you can use it like that :
[image]

Comment: What if we don't use texture coordinate node?

Comment: I think the Texture Coordinate node is only necessary if you haven't unwrapped your object